# Rpart Error with Anova: `Error in !isord : invalid argument type`

Tags: r, data-modeling, decision-tree, anova, rpart

I'm running below code to call rpart function but it keeps giving me error `Error in !isord : invalid argument type`

```
# set arguments for rpart function

group.target.metric <- "loan_amount"
group.data.variables <- c(data.config$dict[is_group == TRUE, variable_name_modeling], group.target.metric)
print(group.data.variables)
group.training.data <- complete.data[, ..group.data.variables]

# run main code

group.tree <- rpart(formula = paste(group.target.metric, "~." ), 
                                    data = group.training.data, 
                                    method = "anova")
```

Can anyone please guide what this could be about?

Rpart version I'm using is `4.1-15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was while creating `data.config$dict` it had missing definitions/datatypes for one variable I was using in the model. To check & update datatype in `complete.data` table use query:

```
complete.data <- UpdateDataTypes(complete.data, data.config$dict)
```